# SharePoint Search Service 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: sharepoint, service, types, media

I'm attempting to query the search service in JavaScript with JQuery and AJAX. I keep getting a 415 Unsupported media type error back. I'm sending a SOAP envelope to the server through this AJAX command:

$.ajax({

```
    url: "http://groups.company.com/_vti_bin/search.asmx",

        beforeSend: function(xhr) {

        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",

        "http://microsoft.com/webservices/OfficeServer/QueryService/GetPortalSearchInfo");

            },

    type: "POST",

    dataType: "text",

    data: soapEnv,

    complete: processResult,

    contentType: "application/text charset=\"utf-8\""

    })
```

I've tried various content types, but I can't see to find any that work. What should it be? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your last line should be:

```
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
```

Answer (score 0):

**It might not be an "incorrect" content-type at all!**

SharePoint will return an HTTP 415 is trying to access a SOAP Service on a site with *anonymous access* because the various SharePoint Web-services *require* authentication. **The body of the result might contain an error message** such as: (Why this is returned with a 415 ... I have no idea.)

> > The following file(s) have been blocked by the administrator: /Lists/MyList/calendar.asp/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

If this is indeed the case then you can *ask* SharePoint to offer up a HTTP 401 Challenge by using [X-RequestForceAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff386830%28v=office.12%29.aspx) header (although this is may not required and I have not tested it myself yet, so YMMV :-).

Just make sure to send the appropriate HTTP WWW-Authenticate header. Note that in C# if a Challenge does not occur the header must be manually enabled, as per [HttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.preauthenticate%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), other environments may have similar issues.

Happy coding.

---

Also, it doesn't matter if SOAP 1.1 or 1.2 are used with SharePoint 2007/2010. Use the Content-Type: (Don't even think about `application/soap-xml`...)

```
text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
```

Or 415's *will* be generated.